# Why admob smart banner doesn't show on landscape mode?

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I have just added admob banners to my app. It works great on each portrait and landscape mode. But when I changed the size to SMART_BANNER, banners still showing on portrait mode, and don't do on landscape.

I see on the LogCat: Failed to load ad: 3

Have any one faced this problem? because i searched everywhere with no result.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem, it will load just give it more time, because it checks the width of the screen and compares to find which ad size is going to fit and then show, but if just banner you have 50*50 who needs to check for width..

hope i am lucid enough

Comment: No it doesn't resize. It stays the same fixed size.

Comment: it calls ad load failed callback, there is nothing to wait here if we see an error

Comment: and you didn't read what author wrote:  *see on the LogCat: Failed to load ad: 3*